# How do I use $form_state['storage']['my_key']?

Tags: forms, 8

The question is clear from the title itself .

I looked in the api specified in :  https://www.drupal.org/node/2310411 .

But it only mention to convert

```
$storage = &$form_state['storage'];
$form_state['storage'] = &$storage;
```

to

```
 $storage = &$form_state->getStorage();
 $form_state->setStorage($storage);
```

But not a key in the $form_state['storage'] ? any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

The example in the documentation link seemed to cause confusion.  Simply set your values in an associative array and use set/get storage.

```
$vals = [
  'name' => 'bob',
  'age' => 50
];

// save the data.
$form_state->setStorage($vals);


// retrieve the data
$vals = $form_state->getStorage();
$str = $vals['name'] . ' is ' . $vals['age'] . ' years old.';
```

https://www.cyberdev.co/how-to-store-temp-form-state-data

Answer (score 1):

In my case updating directly using setStorage breaks my submission.
It would be better to get the storage before to update it to avoid to override/delete some stuffs that other modules whould have done before.

```
function hook_form_alter or equivalent () {
  $storage = &$form_state->getStorage();
  $storage['uid'] = $user->id();

  // Or
  $storage =$form_state->getStorage();
  $storage['uid'] = $user->id();
  $form_state->setStorage($storage);
}

// In my submit custom function 
function submitCustomFunction () {
  $storage = $form_state->getStorage();
  // You would add some test 
  $user = User::load($storage['uid']);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to get the storage at all. You can use FormStateInterface::set() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3Aset/9.4.x, and FormStateInterface::get() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3Aget/9.4.x

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use `$form_state['storage']['my_key']`

The confusion is that the above key is for Drupal 7, but the OP is using Drupal 8. As can be seen from the thread title, `$form_state` is an array, but the tags of the thread show the user is on Drupal 8. Between Drupal 7 and Drupal 8, `$form_state` was switched from an array to an object of type [`Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/interface/FormStateInterface/9.4.x)

Answer (score -1):

The example uses the reference. It's okay if you do not need one. So

```
$storage = $form_state->getStorage();
$form_state->setStorage($storage);
```

also working.

Comment: didnt get what you are talking about . I want to use a key in $form_state['storage'] like **$form_state['storage']['value'] = 'something';**

Comment: You can use set()/get() directly, instead of having to get the storage as an array.

Comment: Forgive my misunderstanding. I should be more active in http://ell.stackexchange.com/. @Berdir is true. So it is `$form_state->set(['storage', 'value'], 'something');`

Comment: Is it **$form_state->setValue('foo', array('bar'));** OR **$form_state->set('foo', array('bar'));** ??